# Program crashes 5 seconds after input?

Tags: c++

I'm making a program, and part of it's purpose is that it needs to be able to separate input into separate strings based on characters.
For example,

game.Lighting is separated into "game" and "Lighting"
game.Properties.Hey is separated into "game" and "Properties" and "Hey"
Basically, it just removes the . and separates them into different strings.

However, when I input what I want the string to be, it works and does it completely fine, then crashes about 5 seconds later with the error "String str was corrupted"

This is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char str[2] = ".";
cin >> str;
char * pch;
printf("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n", str);
pch = strtok(str, ".");
while (pch != NULL)
{
    printf("Getting %s then ", pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, ".");
}
Sleep(5000);
return 0;
}
```

I changed char str[] = "." to char str[2] = "."

However, I'm now getting the error (this is AFTER the program has compiled and ran, then it crashes) "String str was corrupted"

Comment: You forgot to put your lighting into orbit.

Comment: What @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str` only reserves space for two bytes as `"."` is a `char[2]`. That's too little space for any C-string longer than one character ("one" not "two" due to the null byte) and so undefined behavior will probably occur.

---

Your using C++ so write your code accordingly! `strtok` is C. `printf` is C. `char[]` is C. Use C++ facilities instead!
Define a `std::string` and then read into it using `std::cin`:

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> str;
```

The `strtok` can easily be implemented in nice C++ with `std::find`, `std::string::find`, `std::for_each`, or some similar utility function.

I came up with this, hoping not needing to be ashamed of myself too badly:

```
std::size_t pos = 0, tmp;
while ((tmp = str.find('.', pos)) != std::string::npos) {
    str[tmp] = '\0';
    std::cout << "Getting " << str.substr(pos) << " then ";
    pos = tmp;
}
std::cout << "Getting " << str.substr(pos) << " then ";
```

Since C++11, we have `<chrono>` and `<thread>`. Yay! Use something like this instead of this ugly, unportable `Sleep`:

```
std::this_thread:sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
```

---

Programming on Windows does not automatically imply anyone to write unportable code!

**Note** that all these functions are usable in C++ but do not belong in a normal, well-written C++(11) program.

Comment: @JStep Your changes? Write them in your question, please.

Comment: @JStep Uhm, you did read my answer, didn't you? Your program effectively has not changed at all since the `2` within the square brackets can very well be omitted here. Read my answer, polish your code, and try again.